# chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener fired when closing Chrome, crashing plugin

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension, it uses `chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener` to execute a content script. This works fine as long as I switch between different chrome windows however, the Listener is also fired when Chrome is closed. In that case the code inside the function leads to a crash of the extension.

I tried chacking for undefined, but that does not seem to be the issue.

The code lookls liks this

```
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function() 
{
        var ctab = chrome.tabs.getCurrent;
        if(typeof  ctab === "undefined")
        {

        }
        else
        {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(ctab.id,{file:"inject.js"}); //THIS LINE CRASHES THE APP WHEN I CLOSE THE BROWSER
        }
});
```

I have a similar problem with a scheduled allert, which also executes the script (which leads to a crash when I close the browser between scheduling and execution).

```
function onAlarm(alarm) 
{
    if (alarm && alarm.name == 'check') 
    {

        var ctab = chrome.tabs.getCurrent;
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(ctab.id,{file:"inject.js"}); //CRASH
        //more code...
```

Does anybody know how to avoid this crash?

**Edit: Working Example**

manifest.json

```
{
 "name": "Rest Extension",
 "description": "Set an Artnet Controler to the background collor",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "version": "1",
 "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "background", "alarms"],
 "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},
 "content_scripts": [{"matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],"js": ["inject.js"]}],
 "browser_action": 
    {
        "default_icon": "16x16.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function() 
{
        var ctab = chrome.tabs.getCurrent;
        if(typeof  ctab === "undefined")
        {

        }
        else
        {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(ctab.id,{file:"inject.js"}); //THIS LINE CRASHES THE APP WHEN I CLOSE THE BROWSER
        }
})
```

all the other files can be empty (including the inject.js)

Comment: What do you mean by crash? Could you create a self-contained example and report the bug at http://crbug.com/new

Comment: It's probably not a chrome bug (I think) but an issue with my programming. With crashing I mean that after closing the browser on the lower right hand side of the screen a notification is shown, that the extension crashed and I can click that notification to restart the extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chrome.tabs.getCurrent is a method: it's not an instance of a Tab object.
You should try this:

```
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function() 
{
    chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(ctab)
    {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(ctab.id, { file: "inject.js" });
    });
});
```

Reference: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-getCurrent

Comment: thanks. I found that checking for undefined is a good ide for this too so I ended up using it like this

chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function() 
{
    chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(ctab)
    {
  if(ctab!="undefined")
  {
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(ctab.id, { file: "inject.js" });
  }
    });
});